# Profile settings for allowing Object creation/modification but no visibility to apex classes or VF pages

Tags: profile, permission-sets

Is there a way to allow a profile to see and edit object settings i.e settings under 'Customize' and 'Create' category but not under 'Develop' or 'Deploy' category.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all objects, custom and standard? No. The closest you can get is "View Setup and Configuration" permission, but that will show other things too.